# Refresh group of elements

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a JSF page which is essentially just rows and columns of data.  Each row's data comes from the attributes of an instance of a class.  Each row has a link on it that when clicked calls a backing bean method which refreshes the data on that row.  The rows are separated by headings which represent the group of rows beneath them. I want to make the heading a link as well, so that it will refresh all of the rows beneath it.  I tried using some javascript like this:

```
function refreshGroup(){
  var obj1 = document.getElementById("refresh0:link0");
  var obj2 = document.getElementById("refresh1:link1");
  window.open(obj1);
  window.open(obj2);
 };
```

but that just opened new tabs.  Is there any way to make it act as though the user clicked on each of the links?  This is what the JSF looks like for the link that calls the backing bean:

```
<h:form id="refresh#{loop.index}" >
  <h:commandLink id="link#{loop.index}" value="#{a.status}" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{a.getCheckAppMonitor}" 
            render=":errs#{loop.index} :refresh#{loop.index} :errs_#{i+1}"
            onevent="refreshMoreLessLinks" />
  </h:commandLink>&nbsp;<img id="img_#{loop.index}" 
                             class="hidden" 
                             src="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</h:form>
```

This is all nested inside of a `c:foreach` loop.

The header link looks like this:

```
<h3><a href="javascript:refreshGroup();">Group 1</a></h3>
```

Edit:

It occurred to me that I need to create a `commandLink` so I can render everything again.  I did this:

```
<h:form id="header1" >
  <h:commandLink class="link" value="Group 1" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{appBean.refresh}" render="@all" />
  </h:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

and it seems work, only it causes my browser (IE8) to crash.  When the browser recovers, I can see that it did in fact update.  Any ideas on what render="@all" is causing my browser to crash?  I changed @all to one element and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This,

```
var obj1 = document.getElementById("refresh0:link0");
window.open(obj1);
```

is not the right way to trigger a click on a [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) instance. You need to invoke its `click()` method instead.

```
var obj1 = document.getElementById("refresh0:link0");
obj1.click();
```