# Click multiple links at once

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have this bit of javascript:

```
 function refreshGroup(){
  var obj1 = document.getElementById("refresh0:link0");
  var obj2 = document.getElementById("refresh1:link1");
  obj1.click();
  obj2.click();
 };
```

and will ultimately be adding several more objects to the list.  Each object is a link on the page.  I want to create a method that refreshes all of the links for a particular group of links.  The links are tied to a backing bean method which updates the data associated with the link.  This does what I want it to except that it waits for each link to finish running before clicking on the next link.  Is there any way to make it click on all of them at once?

Edit:

Here's the bit of code that I'm trying to simulate clicking on (JSF):

```
<h:form id="refresh#{loop.index}" >
  <h:commandLink class="link" id="link#{loop.index}" value="#{a.status}" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{a.getCheckAppMonitor}" 
            render=":errs#{loop.index} :refresh#{loop.index} :errs_#{i+1}"
        onevent="refreshMoreLessLinks" />
  </h:commandLink>&nbsp;<img id="img_#{loop.index}"
                             class="hidden"
                             src="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</h:form>
```

JSF generates this into something that looks like this:

```
<FORM id=refresh0 encType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded method=post 
  name=refresh0 action=/appmonitor/faces/appmonitorgreeting.xhtml><INPUT 
  value=refresh0 type=hidden name=refresh0> <A id=refresh0:link0 
  onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'errs0 refresh0 errs_1',{'onevent':refreshMoreLessLinks});return false" 
  href="http://localhost:8080/appmonitor/faces/appmonitorgreeting.xhtml#">OK</A>&nbsp;<IMG 
  id=img_0 class=hidden 
  src="appmonitorgreeting_xhtml_files/ajax-loader.gif"><INPUT 
  id=javax.faces.ViewState value=7494473519347208075:5184408304577602221 
  type=hidden name=javax.faces.ViewState autocomplete="off"> </FORM>
```

Comment: Have you considered creating just a single JSF action method which invokes all those target methods and then execute exactly that single action method by a single click?

Comment: @BalusC Are you saying I should have a `commandLink` which calls this for each object: `listener="#{a.getCheckAppMonitor}"`? I created a method which does that, but couldn't get `render=@all` to work.  see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257732/refresh-group-of-elements)

Comment: It'd be helpful if you describe "crash" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective.

Comment: Any idea if IE has logs somewhere?  I get a message box that says IE has stopped working, do you want to restart the program.  I click yes, and it recovers the tab.

Comment: Okay, which JSF impl/version are you using? Have you tried `@all` on a minimalistic page with just a `<html><h:head/><h:body><h:form><h:commandButton><f:ajax>`? IE8 is known to crash at most weird moments, see also e.g. https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2873

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say, I have gotten @all to work before, it's just giving me problems on this one.  I need to overhaul my code anyway.  I understand `<c:foreach>` wasn't really meant for JSF.  Maybe if I use `dataTable` it will be easier to rerender.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to spoof click events.

Call the function behind the click event instead.

Treat the DOM as a view, not a model.

Comment: I'm using JSF and the events that the links fire are cryptic to me.

Comment: Then there's your problem right there. Untangle that mess. There is only so much abuse a piece of code can take before it's become completely unmaintainable.

Comment: Ok, not sure where to begin. Please see edits above.

Comment: Whilst I agree your sentiment, you're actually not concretely answering the question. Better post a comment as long as you have no idea how the generated HTML/JS output look like.

Answer (score -1):

**Is there any way to make it click on all of them at once?**

As per my knowledge, its not possible.Because clicking the element adds an event in the event queue managed by browser.
When you execute the statement `obj1.click();`, it registers the click event attached with `obj1`. When this event reaches the front of event queue, browser calls the corresponding event handler attached.
While some event handler code is executing, all the other events triggered are added in the queue and they wait for their turn to move to the front of queue.So you can  click on elements one after another but the event handlers attached with them will execute one at a time.

 **Reason: Because JavaScript uses single thread of execution**

If one event handler is doing a large calculation, all the events triggered will have to wait for that calculation to complete.
**try this fiddle :** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3K8Hh/18/)

Comment: Uhm, those links fire each an ajax request which are by default asynchronous. It's just JSF who puts them in a queue by using `async="false"` in order to ensure the integrity of the view state.

Comment: @BalusC whatever event happens,it goes to event queue once.Even the event handler making an **asynchronous request** has to wait if some blocking function is being executed.The only difference is the asynchronous request leaves the event queue and registers a callback on response arrival.The above answer states the case of synchronous request which are blocking.If you think the answer is yes, share me a link which says more than 1 events can be handled by the javascript simultaneously.

Comment: From the question: *" it waits for each link to finish running"* In other words, the next ajax request is waiting until response of the previous ajax is retrieved and finished with processing. This is not the default behavior in case of asynchronous requests. Normally, the next ajax request is fired immediately once the previous ajax request is successfully fired (without waiting for its response as in case with `async="false"`).

Comment: @BalusC The above answer which we have given is in context of synchronous request.If you think its wrong,can you Please tell us solution to get the desired behavior using Synchronous requests?